# Call a PHP function dynamically

Tags: php

Is there a way to call a function through variables?

For instance, I want to call the function Login(). Can I do this:

```
$varFunction = "Login"; //to call the function
```

Can I use $varFunction?

Comment: yes, PHP supports this. But I would strongly suggest not to use it, unless you're a masochist or planning some sabotage

Comment: hi, actually the reason for this is because i would like to have the same function name, but for different modules. so for instance Login module and Profile module both have a function call main()

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel Why wouldn't you use it? A place where it is quite useful is the routing portion of MVC software - where URLs map to controllers and methods.

Comment: "the reason for this is because i would like to have the same function name, but for different modules" --- now this would simply be separate classes and having the same method name is fine as you chain different objects with different var names. Even back then, why would you have multiple "login" function names? Even just one with that name sounds ambiguous.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Yes, you can:

```
$varFunction();
```

Or:

```
call_user_func($varFunction);
```

Ensure that you validate $varFunction for malicious input.

---

For your modules, consider something like this (depending on your actual needs):

```
abstract class ModuleBase {
  public function main() {
    echo 'main on base';
  }
}

class ModuleA extends ModuleBase {
  public function main() {
    parent::main();
    echo 'a';
  }
}

class ModuleB extends ModuleBase {
  public function main() {
    parent::main();
    echo 'b';
  }
}

function runModuleMain(ModuleBase $module) {
  $module->main();
}
```

And then call runModuleMain() with the correct module instance.

Comment: hey tks.. i think i will use this. is there a possiblility that web hosting company will disable this function??

Comment: This is just a script, so if they disable this you probably will not be able to run any code.

Comment: The call_user_func function works very well in some cases. For example, you will get an error when you assign a dynamic function to the property of the class within the class and you want to run an operator to run the class property within the class. Because php thinks that you are running a same name method called and gives an error. In this case, call_user_func is a nice solution.

Answer (score 6):

You can use...

```
$varFunction = "Login";
$varFunction();
```

...and it goes without saying to make sure that the variable is trusted.

Comment: hey tks this works too. however, wats the different between this and call_user_func();??

Comment: @nuttynibbles None really, the version I mentioned is more syntactic sugar for the function call. There are probably some minor differences, but I'm not sure what.

Answer (score 3):

If it's in the same class:

```php
$funcName = 'Login';

// Without arguments:
$this->$funcName();

// With arguments:
$this->$funcName($arg1, $arg2);

// Also acceptable:
$this->{$funcName}($arg1, $arg2)
```

If it's in a different class:

```php
$someClass = new SomeClass(); // create new if it doesn't already exist in a variable
$someClass->$funcName($arg1, $arg2);

// Also acceptable:
$someClass->{$funcName}($arg1, $arg2)
```

---

**Tip**:

If the function name is dynamic as well:

```php
$step = 2;

$this->{'handleStep' . $step}($arg1, $arg2);
// or
$someClass->{'handleStep' . $step}($arg1, $arg2);
```

This will call `handleStep1()`, `handleStep2()`, etc. depending on the value of `$step`.

Answer (score 2):

```
 <?php
  $fxname = 'helloWorld';

  function helloWorld(){
    echo "What a beautiful world!";
  }

  $fxname(); //echos What a beautiful world!
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

I successfully call the function as follows:

```
$methodName = 'Login';
$classInstance = new ClassName();
$classInstance->$methodName($arg1, $arg2, $arg3);
```

It works with PHP 5.3.0+

I'm also working in Laravel.

Answer (score 0):

You really should consider using classes for modules, as this would allow you to both have consistent code structure and keep method names identical for several modules. This will also give you the flexibility in inheriting or changing the code for every module.

On the topic, other than calling methods as stated above (that is, using variables as function names, or [call_user_func_](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php)* functions family), starting with PHP 5.3 you can use [closures](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) that are dynamic anonymous functions, which could provide you with an alternative way to do what you want.