# How to hold echo result in a variable without using echo or print in php?

Tags: php, eloquent

I am creating dynamic query through the loop as a string and wants to run that query and hold the result in a variable then return that result as json for ajax purpose.
But the problem is here if I echo the query that stop executing further and just return query itself.

```
  $data = 'Share::all();';
  ob_start();
  echo $data; // stop executing here
  $returnData = ob_get_contents();
  ob_end_clean();
  return $returnData;
```

Comment: You seems to `echo` on `$data`.  And `$data` is simply the string `'Share::all();'`. Where is the query that you're talking about?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php - call a function dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4646991/php-call-a-function-dynamically)

Comment: hmm this looks interesting 04FS

Comment: Koala Yeung I thing you didn't get my point

Comment: If you turn on output buffering, it will hold the printed results in the buffer and not display at all unless you finish it with ob_end_clean() or ob_flush(). So, what is your question?

Comment: @mohsin: Please make your point more understandable.

Answer (score 1):

### Direct Eloquent Call

I think you might actually need this one line instead of all the code you wrote:

```php
return Share::all()->toArray();
```

Printing a piece of php code (i.e. `'Share::all();'` in your case) as string does not execute the code. And it certainly will not give you the result of executing that code.

### Using Output Buffer

Or perhaps you want to use the dangerous [eval](https://www.php.net/eval) to parse output of the code? In that case:

```php
$data = 'echo "hello world";';

$returnData = (function ($code) {
  ob_start();
  eval($code); // stop executing here
  return ob_get_clean();
})($data);

var_dump($returnData);
```

Please note that the return data can only be string. It can never be anything other than plain string. Thus it doesn't really make sense to me if you want to pass the "query result" with output buffer.

### Simply `eval`

You are probably actually thinking about this.

```php
$data = 'return Share::all()->toArray();';
$returnData = eval($data);
var_dump($returnData);
```

But you'd get wield result with modern namespaced PHP code. Plus running `eval` is really not recommended.

Comment: no dear sorry this is not what I asked, I think 04FS got my point. thank you

Comment: I somehow doubt that.